# Java Object Serialization: serialize a Hashtable, then deserialize it in a HashMap

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap, deserialization, hashtable

Java object serialization: I serialized this type of Hashtable for example of (Integer,Employee) and when I deserialize this, I would like to put the output in a HashMap. Is this possible? Because I get the java.lang.ClassCastException

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -7260877684654746408L;
  private String name;
  private int age;

  Employee(String n, int a) {
    name=n;
    age=a;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "Name: "+name+". "+"Age: "+age+".";
  }

}

    public class Test {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hashtable<Integer, Employee> ht = new Hashtable<Integer, Employee>() {
          {
            put(1, new Employee("John", 37));
            put(2, new Employee("Julia", 36));
          }
        };

        //HashMap<Integer,Employee> hm = new HashMap<Integer,Employee>();


        try {
          FileOutputStream outSer = new FileOutputStream("outSer.ser");
          ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(outSer);
          os.writeObject(ht);
          os.close();

          FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("outSer.ser");
          ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(input);
          HashMap<Integer,Employee> hm= (HashMap<Integer, Employee>)ois.readObject();
          ois.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

    }
```

Comment: Show your efforts

Comment: Show the Employee & Person class too

Comment: @sForSujit Why? They don't change the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Yes. But not the way you coded it. You would have to create your own `HashMap` and load it from the `HashTable`:

```
HashMap<Integer,Employee> hm= new HashMap<>((HashTable<Integer, Employee>)ois.readObject());
```